# push_back getting a vector of last element

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to read a list of points by their x co-ordinate into a vector. However, I keep getting a vector of the last element.
For example, if the input is

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

The output will be

```
3 3
3 3
3 3
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

typedef Point* ppt;

int main()
{
    //read input
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<ppt> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        Point p;
        ppt pp = &p;
        cin >> pp->x;
        cin >> pp->y;
        v.push_back(pp);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        ppt p = v.at(i);
        cout << p->x << " " << p->y << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I read the documentation. If I understand correctly, vector::push_back(pp) copies the pointer and insert the copied value in the end of v. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has Undefined Behavior, because here

```
ppt p = v.at(i);
cout << p->x << " " << p->y << endl;
```

You're trying to access an already destructed object:

```
{
    Point p;
    ppt pp = &p;
    cin >> pp->x;
    cin >> pp->y;
    v.push_back(pp);

} // p is destructed here, so you have a dangling pointer in the vector
```

Instead of using vector of pointers to `Point` use `std::vector<Point>` and add objects instead of pointers:

```
std::vector<Point> v;

//...

Point p;

cin >> p.x;
cin >> p.y;
v.push_back(p);
```

Comment: where is the object destructed and why??could you explain more?

Comment: @Will When you do push_back to vector , it uses copy constructor to copy element to vector, So plain pointer is copied (shallow copy) to the vector , As Pointer is pointing to object on stack , It goes out of scope when it goes out of scopoe/block "}".

Comment: @Will The variable `p` is defined locally and after each iteration it is destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        Point p;
        ppt pp = &p;
        cin >> pp->x;
        cin >> pp->y;
        v.push_back(pp);
    }
```

**this code is wrong**, you construct the object `Point p` inner the for loop, but when you run over the for loop, the object `Point p` is destroied, but you store the address of `Point p` into the vector, after the destroy of object `Point p`, the contents in the vector is invalid.

You can do like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
    ppt pp = new Point();
    cin >> pp->x;
    cin >> pp->y;
    v.push_back(pp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration of your first loop, you are creating a variable of type `Point` and a pointer to it, but in the end of this loop, that variable is destroyed and your pointer becomes a dangling,

In the next iteration, you create another variable and do the same thing on the **"same location in the memory"**

In the end, all your pointers are in fact pointing to a destroyed object and called dagling, but they refer to one location, and this location has the value of your lastly saved point.

---

This code should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

typedef Point ppt;

int main()
{
    //read input
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<ppt> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        Point p;
        cin >> p.x;
        cin >> p.y;
        v.push_back(p);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cout << v[i].x << " " << v[i].y << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, that is not the case.  If the output appears to conform to that explanation, it is purely by chance. The behavior is actually undefined.

Comment: The main point in your explanation - that the pointers probably all hold the same address - it very likely true in practice but as Benjamin says not guaranteed.  More importantly, "null" does not mean pointing-to-a-destructed-object, which is the sense in which you've used it.  A null pointer is very specifically `== 0`, which the pointers in the `vector` will not be.  So "and your pointer becomes a null pointer" isn't true - it becomes "invalid" or ["dangling"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  Ditto for "all your pointers are in fact null pointers".